# Docker container cannot start

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have built a docker image to run a jenkins server in and after creating a container for this image, I find that the container remains on exit status, and never starts. Even when I attempt to start the container with the UI.

Here are the steps I have taken, and perhaps I am missing something?

```
docker pull jenkins/jenkins
sudo mkdir /var/jenkins_home   
docker run -p 9080:8080 -d -v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins
```

I already have java running on the port 8080, maybe this is impacting the container status?

```
java    2968 user   45u  IPv6 0xbf254983f0051d87      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

Not sure why its running on this port, I have attempted to kill the PID but it recreates itself.

Following the comments:

```
docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES
fc880ccd31ed   jenkins/jenkins   "/usr/bin/tini -- /u…"   3 seconds ago   Exited (1) 2 seconds ago             vigorous_lewin


docker logs vigorous_lewin
touch: setting times of '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': No such file or directory
Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?
```

Comment: After you run it, can you do `docker ps -a` and then `docker logs <container name>` and add the logs to your post, please?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md) say

> NOTE: Avoid using a bind mount from a folder on the host machine into
> /var/jenkins_home, as this might result in file permission issues (the
> user used inside the container might not have rights to the folder on
> the host machine). If you really need to bind mount jenkins_home,
> ensure that the directory on the host is accessible by the jenkins
> user inside the container (jenkins user - uid 1000) or use -u
> some_other_user parameter with docker run.

So they recommend using a docker volume rather than a bind mount like you do. If you have to use a bind mount, you need to ensure that UID 1000 can read and write the host directory.

The easiest solution is to run the container as root by adding `-u root` to your `docker run` command, like this

```
docker run -p 9080:8080 -d -v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -u root jenkins/jenkins
```

That's not as secure though, so depending on what environment you're running your container in, that might not be a good idea.

Comment: Great suggestion although this does not make any changes for my particular case. I have attempted normal installations, by normal I mean without reference to `/var` directory. And directly installing the image/container, however, no server appears. I'll probably just continue digging to find this out.